# Compare two data tables and insert into another table based on column name in C#

Tags: c#

I have two data tables `Table1` and `Table2`. I want to compare a value `SourceField` and insert the row of both table into a new data table.

Table #1 - Mapping table

```
Key    SourceField 
------------------
null   name 
A101   V1 
A102   V2 
A103   V3
```

Table #2 - Source table

```
Name   V1    V2     V3
-----------------------
10001  1     2      3
```

Table #3 - Output table

```
Name   Value   Key
--------------------
10001   1      A101
10001   2      A102
10001   3      A103
```

Regards,
Manish

Comment: what have you tried? any errors?

Comment: I am new in .Net i don't know how i can Put in table3 in C# in given format, please help me on this

Comment: The values from table 2 *aren't in* table 2; did you mean the values to be `V1` etc to match?

Answer (score 1):

For `DataTable` , following solution will work for you.

I tested it. I used the same structure that you mentioned in the question.

```
DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
table1.Columns.Add("Key");
table1.Columns.Add("SourceField");

table1.Rows.Add("A101", "V1");
table1.Rows.Add("A102", "V2");
table1.Rows.Add("A103", "V3");

DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
table2.Columns.Add("Name");
table2.Columns.Add("V1");
table2.Columns.Add("V2");
table2.Columns.Add("V3");

table2.Rows.Add("10001", 1, 2, 3);

DataTable table3 = new DataTable();
table3.Columns.Add("Name");
table3.Columns.Add("Value");
table3.Columns.Add("Key");

// LOOP FOR COMPARING THE DIFFERENT COLUMNS AND VALUES FROM DIFFERENT DATATABLES
foreach (DataRow drtable1 in table1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataRow drtable2 in table2.Rows)
    {
        if ( drtable2[Convert.ToString(drtable1["SourceField"])] != null)
        {
            table3.Rows.Add(drtable2["Name"], drtable2[Convert.ToString(drtable1["SourceField"])], drtable1["Key"]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Result (snap from Visual Studio)**

[image]

**UPDATE**

Need to add one more condition in loop for checking blank value for `Key` column.

```
// LOOP FOR COMPARING THE DIFFERENT COLUMNS AND VALUES FROM DIFFERENT DATATABLES
foreach (DataRow drtable1 in table1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataRow drtable2 in table2.Rows)
    {
        if (drtable2[Convert.ToString(drtable1["SourceField"])] != null && Convert.ToString(drtable1["Key"]).Trim() != string.Empty)
        {
             table3.Rows.Add(drtable2["Name"], drtable2[Convert.ToString(drtable1["SourceField"])], drtable1["Key"]);
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks it's working but for name row in table 1 is null  repeating for each row  because   key is null how we remove this for each field

Comment: @MANISH Check the update in the answer and mark as answer/upvote if it is useful. Let me know still have any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `DataSet`:

```
DataSet dset = new DataSet();

DataTable datatable3 = new DataTable("OutputTable");
datatable3.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name",typeof(string)));
datatable3.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(int)));
datatable3.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Key", typeof(string)));


//do a foreach or any other operation here
//you can add a new row to the datatable like that: 
drow["Name"] = "10001";
drow["Value"] = 3;
drow["Key"] = "A103";
DataRow drow = datatable3.NewRow();
datatable3.Rows.Add(drow);

//after adding ALL rows, you have to add the datatable to the dataset
dset.Tables.Add(datatable3);
```

Loop through an existing dataset (I suppose you already have ds1 and ds2 as seperate datatables):

```
foreach (DataRow row1 in datatable1.Rows)
{
  foreach (DataRow row2 in datatable2.Rows)
  {
     //example comparasion
     if (row1["SourceField"] == row2["SourceField")
     {
       datatable3.Rows.Add(....) //see above examples how to add a row
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you performing comparison of values based on column names? He has clearly mentioned that what result he wants? I think you are answer is not pointing to the solution. All you provided is creating a DataTable and DataSet only. Please update the answer.

Comment: @GaurangDave Well your solution is already complete. I just tried to provide a way to start solving the problem, because I think complete tutorials should not be on here. I'll add an example of comparasion, but I think we should keep your answer as solution here

Comment: Thanks :) I would suggest you edit your answer with some explanation or sample as I found it little bit of misleading from actual concept. Hope you understand.